# Keeping the state of Zoom Level on page refresh in OpenStreetMap

Tags: javascript, php, openstreetmap

In reference to the Open Street Map for Heatmap tutorial in this link

```
http://www.d3noob.org/2014/02/generate-heatmap-with-leafletheat-and.html
```

I want to know how could I keep the state of zoom level when I refresh the page. Suppose I changed the blur value via $_POST and the page refreshes then I go back to the default zoom(10). But I want to be at the same zoom level I was when I just wanted to change the blur value.

Answer (score 0):

Use leaflet.hash

http://mlevans.github.io/leaflet-hash/

So the zoom and the position are saved in the window.hash object